# ASP.Net MVC + static ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

There is a ASP.Net MVC Project. In global.asax there is a definition:

```
    public class Application : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpSessionState> UserSessions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpSessionState>();
...
```

It's being used in a LoginController like this:

```
public class LoginController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult DoLogin(AuthorizationViewModel authorizationViewModel)
    {
        ...
        var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
        Application.UserSessions.TryAdd(session.SessionID, session);
```

It was working well enough, but now I had to add a new assembly (class library project) with alternative LoginController. This library is being loaded on startup and AlternativeLoginController is being registered in Windsor container). I've do it like this:

```
public class AlternativeLoginController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult DoLogin(AuthorizationViewModel authorizationViewModel)
    {
        ...
        var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
        Application.UserSessions.TryAdd(session.SessionID, session);
```

Native DoLogin (in Web project) and mine (in additional assembly project) should work similar, as I though. Native DoLogin works perfectrly, every new user is being added to the Application.UserSessions ConcurrentDictionary without troubles. But, when mine DoLogin is invoked, Application.UserSessions.Count is shown as 0 no matter there is authorized users on server or not. And when Application.UserSessions.TryAdd is reached, all the users authorized by native DoLogin is getting unauthorized.
How is it possible? Why public static Application.UserSessions works differently inside of web project code and Additional assembly code?

Upd: I've found the bug. Someone who was responsible for .dll before me have added a logs. On every call to DoLogin he was storing a log file in .xml format in... bin folder. Ta-dam! Since bin folder is modified, server immediately restarts, all the sessions is closed and I see an empty Application.UserSessions.

Comment: What exactly is the 'additional assembly project'? Is it a separate class library which produces an assembly which is used in the MVC project?

Comment: Yes, it is class library. It's being loaded on startup and it's controller getting registered in Windsor container.

Comment: Only thing I can think of that it is in a different `AppDomain` for some reason.

Comment: Possibly the problem is in the way Windsor registers the dll. Can you change the way Windsor in configured?

Comment: Every assembly is getting load into the same AppDomain by simply calling Assembly.LoadFile(). I'm register my controller in Windsor manually by calling container.Install(new AuthorizationInstaller()); in PreAppStart

Answer (score 2):

Try using HttpContext.Application object to store objects you need to share across the web application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx

You can set it in Global.asax.cs

```
Application.Set("UserSessions", new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpSessionState>())
```

You can use it in MVC to get the instance of UserSessions

```
((ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpSessionState>)HttpContext.Application.Get("UserSessions"))
```

Of course you'll lose the contents on application recycle.

Comment: Suddenly, I can't modify global.asax.cs code. I'm only free to modify my dll.